# How to merge two NodebyID into one variable?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

I am using Umbraco and I would like to add two variables together that will display articles in both children.

```
var nodes = Model.NodeById(1195).Children();
var nodes2 = Model.NodeById(1201).Children();

var test = Model.NodesById(nodes, nodes2);
```

It's not working and throwing an error. Is there another way to do this?
I found this on the forum board, but It doesn't seem to work for me.

link: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/47078-how-to-merger-DynamicNode?p=0#comment168589

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

```
DynamicNodeList nodes = Model.NodeById(1195).Children();
DynamicNodeList nodes2 = Model.NodeById(1201).Children();

var allNodes = nodes.Concat(nodes2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit primitive (but without knowing more of the context) something like this should work:

```
string parentIds = "1195,1201";
string[] parentArray = parentIds.Split(',');

DynamicNodeList allNodes = new DynamicNodeList();

foreach (var x in parentArray);
    foreach (var y in Library.NodeById(x).Children()) {
         var thisNode = Library.NodeById(y);
         if (thisNode.Id != 0)  {
             allNodes.Add(thisNode);
         }
    }
}
```